# rails devise custom responses when using i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-i18n, devise-confirmable

I am currently using rails as backend, and have i18n works with devise.

I want to return a string to the client when user is not confirmed when login.

However, it will always return the error message in the locale only.

I have something like this

```
before_action :check_user_confirmation, only: :create

def check_user_confirmation
  user = User.find(params[:email])
  return render json: { error: 'not_confirmed', message: 'custom error message' }, status: :unauthorized unless user.confirmed?
end
```

It will always return `error: translation missing: en-GB.devise.failure.user.unconfirmed`
(I removed the translation to make it more clear)

Any idea how can I send a custom response?

Comment: Have you overridden the default devise controller?

Comment: Yes, I have overridden :create in sessions_controller, and I can return custom response when password is not correct, but not when is not confirmed

Comment: You can place your custom text in devise.en.yml and another language file. No need to show a message in your above code.

Comment: but I want to pass sth like `not_confirmed: true` (for example), for client to  determine whether to do an action or not